Interoperability/Bridging with Solana and other chains
I am conducting a study for the university that has to do with Solana and interoperability with other platforms.
Could someone tell me where to find documentation to develop a simple transaction with another platform like Ethereum for example?
I would also like to know if intermediaries are required in interoperability mechanisms with other platforms.
Finally, I would like to know what are the future plans of the blockchain, if there is a road map for the following years
Thank you so much!

If you're looking for interoperability/bridging options, you can look at the following:

Wormhole: https://wormhole.com/
DeBridge: https://debridge.finance/

